# Android - Type mismatch with LiveData variable

Tags: android, android-livedata, type-mismatch, mutablelivedata

I have the following in my viewmodel :

```
// hold the list of comments of a Post
private val _commentsOfPost = MutableLiveData<PagedList<Comment>>()

val commentsOfPost : LiveData<PagedList<Comment>> = _commentsOfPost

fun getCommentsOfPost(postId: Long){
     _commentsOfPost.value = commentRepository.getCommentsOfPost(postId)   // <--- TYPE MISMATCH
}
```

So, what happens is that whenever the `getCommentsOfPost()` is called by the Fragment, it retrieves a `PagedList` of `Comment` instances belonging to a `Post` specified by its ID.

But Android tells me about a `Type mismatch` ( see the arrow in the codesnippet above):

```
Required: PagedList<Comment>?
Found: LiveData<PagedList<Comment>>
```

For the sake of completeness, this is the `getCommentsOfPost()` interface:

```
fun getCommentsOfPost(postId: Long) : LiveData<PagedList<Comment>>
```

How can I change it so that this error disappears ?

Answer (score 0):

You should return to PagedList,
sample:

```
fun getCommentsOfPost(postId: Long) : PagedList<Comment> {
   // your code
   // return PagedList<Comment>
}
```